# complex matrix with $m^2=m=m^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $m=(m_{ij})\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a matrix with $m^2=m=m^*$, where $m^*=\overline{m}^t$. Can $m$ have negative entries?

My thoughts: I think yes, but it is similar to diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $\subseteq \{0,1\}$, i.e. to a matrix which has no negative entries.

Is it wrong?

Comment: How about $$\frac12\pmatrix{1&-1\\-1&1}?$$

Comment: thank you, I understand. I.e. it can have negative entries. Do you want to turn it into an answer?